# In Doctrine2, cannot remove unidirectional many-to-one relation (cannot set to null)

Tags: postgresql, doctrine-orm, many-to-one

I have an Authentication entity that works like a user entity, and a Country entity which has a property related to Authentication entity unidirectionally:

```
/**
 * @var Authentication
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Authentication")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="`archived_by`", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $archivedBy;

/**
 * @param Authentication $archivedBy
 * @return Country
 */
public function setArchivedBy(Authentication $archivedBy = null)
{
    $this->archivedBy = $archivedBy;

    return $this;
}
```

As for documentation, the join column is by default nullable.

When I want to set a user to this archivedBy property in a listener, it works  as expected:

```
public function preRemove(LifecycleEventArgs $event)
{
    $entity = $event->getObject();
    $entity->setArchivedBy($this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser());

    $om = $event->getObjectManager();
    $om->persist($entity);
    $om->flush();
}
```

But when I want to set this property to null (want to remove the relation) in its controller, it does not work as expected:

```
$country->setArchivedBy(null);
```

In Doctrine2 debug of Symfony profiler, I see that the sql query does not include "SET archived_by = null", such that:

```
UPDATE "country" SET "archived_at" = NULL, "updated_by" = '80fa198a-3216-46cd-aedb-64ce7ff27801', "updated_at" = '2017-08-29 17:11:59+0300' WHERE "id" = '8149132e-2e28-4423-bc72-471751b5fcd3';
```

So the problem may occur in Doctrine's internal query builder.

When I explicitly define nullable=true such that,

```
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="`archived_by`", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
```

nothing changes, as expected, because it is already by default.

In [Doctrine2 documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#removing-associations), I couldn't find anything.

All I need is to set archivedBy property to null.

Details:

- I use postgresql. (The archived_by column is nullable there.)
- Doctrine ORM 2.5 & Doctrine Bundle 1.6

Comment: Please do not add solved to your question, accept the answer that solved your problem see [tour], you may need to wait some before you can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to believe that the problem is about a Doctrine limitation.

When I remove the quotes in the column name annotation, it works as expected; such that,

```
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="archived_by", referencedColumnName="id")
```

instead of

```
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="`archived_by`", referencedColumnName="id")
```

Then Doctrine produces SQL queries with

```
SET archived_by = NULL
```

It may be reported as a bug, but it is not a bug. In [Doctrine2 documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/limitations-and-known-issues.html#identifier-quoting-and-legacy-databases), it is clearly stated that:

> You cannot quote join column names.

So removing unnecessary quotes solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

use this annotation:

```
@ORM\JoinColumn(name="`archived_by`", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
```

After launch into your command line:

```
bin/consone doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Delete the cache and retry to make this:

```
$country->setArchivedBy(null);
```

And this works fine for me

Comment: Actually, nullable = true is default. I explicitly used it and tried to update the schema, it says: "Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata." It is nullable in the database too. I deleted the cache and nothing changes. Thanks.